# Is it possible to send push notifications with emojis through AWS' SNS?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I've tried adding Unicode char to the message string. Like this: "Some message blablabla \u1F601". But it is shown as a literal string. How can i make it so that the Unicode character is interpreted? Or is there another way to send push notifications with emojis through AWS' SNS?

Comment: you have to show notification message in custum EmojiTextView which will decode the Unicode and show emoji respectedly. example like this https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji

Comment: Thanks :) How about IOS?